# Remove duplicates function doesnt work (C++ Linked Lists)

Tags: c++, pointers

I've been trying to write a function for an assignment that removes duplicate entries in a linked list but it just doesnt work no matter what I try. It either does nothing or crashes.
displayList works fine on its own so it's not the problem here.

```
void List::delNode(int pos){
    if(isEmpty()){
        cout<<"The list is empty."<<endl;
        return;
    }else{
    Student* temp;
    temp = head;
    curr = temp->next;
    if(pos == 0){
        head = curr;
        delete temp;
    }else{
        for(int i = 1; i<pos-1; i++){
            curr = curr->next;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = curr->next;
        delete curr;
    }
  }
}

void List::removeDuplicate(List &l){
    float gpa;
    bool flag = false;
    string name;
    Student *copy, *temp;
    curr = head;
    for(int i = 0; curr != NULL; i++){
        cout<<"pass "<<i<<endl;
        copy = curr;
        temp = curr->next;
        gpa = curr->S_gpa;
        name = curr->S_name;
        for(int e = i; temp != NULL; e++){
            flag = false;
            if(temp->S_gpa == gpa && temp->S_name == name){
                copy->next = temp->next;
                l.delNode(e);
                copy = curr;
                temp = curr->next;
                flag = true;
                e = i;
            }
            if(flag){

            }else{
                //copy = copy->next;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    displayList();
}
```

Comment: The variable `curr` is used in `removeDuplicate(List &l)` and in `delNode(int pos)`

Comment: Yes its the lists' pointer to the current node

Comment: `curr` can point to just deleted memory after calling `delNode` when `pos > 0` and the `List &l` is the same as `this`

Comment: Okay I understand so what should I do? It basically deletes the duplicate entry but also deletes every other entry leaving only the head or it immediately crashes upon deleting the duplicate

Answer (score 0):

`List::delNode(int pos)` on its own looks OK. Except `curr` should be a local variable, like `temp` is.

`List::removeDuplicate(List &l)` accepts a list to remove from, but loops and checks its own elements. Either use `List &l` for all data, or none.

In `List::removeDuplicate(List &l)`, the `curr` should probably also be a local variable.

When you have found a duplicate, you just want to move to the next node, then delete the current node. Deleting the current node, changes the index of the next node, so correct for that by decreasing `e`:

```cpp
temp = temp->next;
delNode(e);
e--;
```

Comment: Okay thanks it doesnt crash now but when the list has more than 2 entries it just deletes the middle ones one by one, doesnt matter if its a duplicate. If the list has just 2 entries then it deletes the duplicate